# Why can I not access the DLC even though I have the Collectors Edition of Rocket League?

Tags: xbox-one, rocket-league

I recently bought the Rocket League Collector's Edition for my Xbox One and the four additional cars got installed straight away. However, when I accessed the garage, the cars from the included DLC packs were not there.

They are not in the Windows Store either, but the game case says they're included on the disc. I have fully installed the game, but the cars still won't appear.

Is my Collector's Edition disc incomplete or do I somehow unlock the cars in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this solution](https://support.505games.com/support/solutions/articles/6000138242-where-is-my-rocket-league-collector-s-edition-dlc-on-xbox-one-):

> Some users have reported only receiving the 4 extra DLC cars in Rocket League: Collector's Edition for the Xbox One.
>
> Not to fear, all of the 3 DLC pack items are there on your disc!  The code included with your game will immediately unlock the 4 additional cars (Aftershock, Esper, Masamune, and Marauder), and as you play through the game, you will unlock everything else, including all of the DLC pack items from Chaos Run, Supersonic Fury, and Revenge of the Battle Cars.